# MySQL subquery as a table (for multiple columns back)

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to a flattening out of a couple of tables in MySQL and not sure how to best optimize it

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/310a8/15

I am getting an EXTRA row in the result set because there is a 2nd "decorator" (last row in the INSERT statement)

I tried to do a LIMIT inside the virtual table JOINS but that doesn't work (because it operates on itself so the ON condition never occurs, resulting in ZERO rows)

The 2 things I can do are

1) Do a GROUP BY a.id at the end of the query
2) Create another column called `rank` and do a `rank = 1` inside the virtual tables

Is it more efficient to do #2 (schema changes, lots of movement) or is the GROUP BY sufficient.  It seems like the best way to get more "specific" is to bite the bullet and do #2 so I can even gauge the "priority" - i.e., if there are 2 "decorators", who is in first position.

Comment: It's not really an extra row because you really do have two decorators for the donuts, so which one do you want to return?  Which one is considered first?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to extend the sub-queries to filter out the duplicate users using a certain criteria. E.g. if you want to select the users with the biggest user_id the query would be:

```
SELECT
 a.id, a.name, 
 b.id as mixer_user_id, 
 b.first_name as mixer_first, b.last_name as mixer_last,
 c.id as baker_user_id, 
 c.first_name as nbaker_first, c.last_name as baker_first,
 d.id as decorator_user_id, 
 d.first_name as decorator_first, d.last_name as decorator_last,
 a.active
FROM
 orders a 
 JOIN (
  SELECT b1.id as id, b1.first_name, b1.last_name, b2.order_id 
  FROM users b1, order_users b2
  WHERE b1.id=b2.user_id and b2.user_type='mixer'
   AND b1.id = (SELECT MAX(user_id) FROM order_users WHERE order_id = b2.order_id AND user_type = b2.user_type)
 ) b ON (a.id = b.order_id)
 JOIN (
  SELECT c1.id as id, c1.first_name, c1.last_name, c2.order_id 
  FROM users c1, order_users c2
  WHERE c1.id=c2.user_id and c2.user_type='baker'
   AND c1.id = (SELECT MAX(user_id) FROM order_users WHERE order_id = c2.order_id AND user_type = c2.user_type)
 ) c ON (a.id = c.order_id)
 JOIN (
  SELECT d1.id as id, d1.first_name, d1.last_name, d2.order_id 
  FROM users d1, order_users d2
  WHERE d1.id=d2.user_id and d2.user_type='decorator'
   AND d1.id = (SELECT MAX(user_id) FROM order_users WHERE order_id = d2.order_id AND user_type = d2.user_type)
 ) d ON (a.id = d.order_id)
WHERE
 a.id in (1001, 1002, 1003);
```

If you had a different RDBMS (say Oracle or MSSQL) you would use CTE to create a grouped order_users table. But as long as you stuck with MySQL you have no choice as to use this in sub-queries.

If you use this query very often you should consider creating VIEW